# VS 2013 Express build menu missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just installed VS 2013 Express. Has the Build menu been removed from VS 2013 Express?  Is there anyway to restore it?

Comment: Do you have a solution open, so there's actually something to be built?

Comment: Yes, tried it with both a Web Forms and MVC project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turn on Tools/Settings/Expert Settings.

Comment: There is no `Settings` option under tools.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the option... I am also facing the same problem and couldn't find the settings option

Comment: Works also for VS 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

This also works in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

[image]